# convert cin after input

Tags: c++, cin

I'm trying to create a tic tac toe game using a matrix, and it runs fine if I have the user input each position as [0][0] or [1][2], etc. However, I want the user to be able to input "a, b, c" and "1, 2, 3", but when I try to change input values and enter a letter into the console, I get:

> Unhandled exception at 0x01294C54 in ConsoleApplication3.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x345D4330.

Is there a way to change the user's input values without this happening?

Here's the first part of the code, and the problem is in the Input function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

char matrix[3][3] = { '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-' };

void Draw()
{
    cout << "  a b c" << endl;
    int row=1; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << row << " ";
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout <<endl;
        row++;
     }
}

void Input()
{
    int pos1, pos2;
    cout << "Pick a place to put your X" << endl;
    cin >> pos1 >> pos2;
    if (pos1 == 'a')
        pos1 = '0';
    if (pos1 == 'b')
        pos1 = '1';
    if (pos1 == 'c')
        pos1 = '2';
    if (pos2 == '1')
        pos2 = '0';
    if (pos2 == '2')
        pos2 = '1';
    if (pos2 == '3')
        pos2 = '2';

    if (matrix[pos1][pos2] != 'O' && matrix[pos1][pos2] != 'X')
    {
        matrix[pos1][pos2] = 'X';
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you dealing with comma delimiters and how do you think reading `a` into an `int` will work? Unsuccessful stream extraction will leave `pos1` and `pos2` uninitialized in pre-c++11 code. That might be happening here.

Comment: Other than that, if you change `pos1` and `pos2` to `char`, `'0'` is not `0` but `48`, `'1'` is not `1` but `49`, etc... That's an access out of range right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing `matrix` using out of bounds indices. The valid indices to access `matrix` are `matrix[0][0]` to `matrix[2][2]`. You are using the character `'0'`, `'1'`, and `'2'` to access the matrix. The numerical value of those, if your system uses ASCII encoding, are 48, 49, and 50.

Also, when your variable is of type `int` and you use:

```
cin >> pos1;
```

the program will not read correctly the input `a`. You need to use:

```
char pos1;
cin >> pos1;
```

to accept `a` as a valid input.

Here's a modified version of your function:

```
void Input()
{
    char c1, c2;
    int pos1, pos2;

    cout << "Pick a place to put your X" << endl;
    cin >> c1 >> c2;

    if (c1 == 'a')
        pos1 = 0;
    else if (c1 == 'b')
        pos1 = 1;
    else if (c1 == 'c')
        pos1 = 2;
    else
    {
       // Error do something
    }

    if (c2 == '1')
        pos2 = 0;
    else if (c2 == '2')
        pos2 = 1;
    else if (c2 == '3')
        pos2 = 2;
    else
    {
       // Error do something
    }

    if (matrix[pos1][pos2] != 'O' && matrix[pos1][pos2] != 'X')
    {
        matrix[pos1][pos2] = 'X';
    }
}
```